# Wordpress редактируемые блоки

Tags: wordpress

Я с wordpress крайне редко работаю и мало что о нем знаю.

Хотелось бы узнать, как сделать, чтобы любые блоки на главной странице были редактируемые. То есть, к примеру:

Есть дизайн, его сверстали. Теперь на главной странице, около 6 блоков и как сделать так, чтобы их можно редактировать с админки.

Visual Composer - не совсем понял, там возможно вытаскивать по блочно в шаблоне?

Или же то, что wordpress обновился, это делается.

Подскажите куда копать.

Comment: Берёшь практически любую современную тему из оф каталога и получаешь блоки на морде десятком разными способными. Я предпочитаю там где виджеты. Напр https://wordpress.org/themes/medical-circle/ https://wordpress.org/themes/spacious/ и др темы этих производителей.

Answer (score 1):

Берите чистый WordPress и стандартную тему, например 2019. В новом WordPress из коробки уже есть редактор блоков Gutenberg, на котором можно собирать восхитительные сайты.

Gutenberg отлично расширяется массой плагинов и аддонов. Неплохо работает с плагином Advanced Custom Fields, собирая блоки под редактор из полей ACF.